# Short story about a group of sci-fi writers sitting around discussing their profession

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

A group of science fiction writers are sitting around taking turn discussing their profession, where they get their inspiration from, various things that have happened to them during their careers.

After a series of reasonably normal anecdotes, one of them tells the others that he woke up one morning in a parallel universe, quite similar to the regular world but with enough differences that he could make a living as a science fiction writer simply by writing about everyday occurrences at home. Meanwhile he searched constantly for a way to return.

The others initially take this in good humour before gradually coming to realise that he's serious, and start pointing out various flaws in his story demonstrating how ridiculous this is. Eventually one of them asks if this true, then how did he ever get back home.

The last line is something like

> "I didn't", he said sadly. "I'm still here."

(I can't remember if the names used are real sci-fi writers, and a sort of inside joke, or fictional).
I would have read it sometime in the mid-80s, probably in an anthology. I think it was in a local library, so the book may have been a few years older.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Sounds very much like Edmond Hamilton's ["Exile"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41424), first published in [*Super Science Stories*, May 1943](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?60798) but anthologized many times (see first link).

The narrator regrets that the talk got round to science fiction, as but for that he wouldn't be "haunted" by the story. The actual last sentences go:

> Carrick shook his head somberly as he rose to leave. "No, I never got back home," he said soberly. "I'm still here."

Comment: Brilliant, that's it! Thanks a million, that's been popping into my head on and off for years. Great to have finally tracked it down!

Comment: But it is online at http://www.docsford.com/document/1881827 - some site I've never come across before.

Comment: Unless [this Spanish translation](https://lecturia.org/cuentos-y-relatos/edmond-hamilton-exilio/2401/) (cannot open the English version linked to above right now) is somehow off, the aspect "he woke up one morning in a parallel universe, quite similar to the regular world" mentioned by the OP doesn't seem quite accurate. Not saying this isn't the story (the OP confirmed this and accepted, after all), but it usually seems helpful to point out both matches and deviations between question and actual story in ID questions, if only to avoid giving rise to wrong expectations to other readers.

Comment: I read this in *Peter Davison's Book of Alien Planets*, which someone gave me as a child. The ending still gives me shivers! @O.R.Mapper, from what i recall, a new power plant is built next to the protagonist's home, and the energy from it somehow lets him create a parallel universe from scratch using his imagination; eventually he inserts himself into that universe, which is our one.

Comment: Sounds rather like Niven's "For a Foggy Night".

Comment: @TomAnderson, only seeing your comment now, but thanks for reminding me - that's where i originally read it!

Comment: This is now available at [archive.org](https://archive.org/stream/supersciencestoriesv04n04194305#page/n87/mode/1up).