# Short story about a sci fi writer in the 1800s who tells a story about going back in time using a mirror

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

I'm looking for a Sci Fi short story about a sci fi writer in the 1800s who tells a story about going back in time using a mirror.  He describes to his friends the barbaric, primitive people he met there.  It goes on for a while with his descriptions, then a friend asks him how he ever got back.  He answers, "I never did get back".

Comment: Going by the punch line, this might be a very muddled recollection if Edmond Hamilton's "Exile" which is described in this old question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/231689/what-is-the-short-story-about-the-science-fiction-writer-who-becomes-trapped-in

Comment: It sounds very like *Exile*, even down to the protagonist complaining about how barbarous the world is. But there is no mirror in *Exile*.

Comment: @JohnRennie Yep. A sci-fi writer trapped in a barbaric world, punch line "I never got back." But no mirror, no time travel, no 1800s. It's like we're mixing up two different stories. That happens.

Comment: @user14111 That was my thought as well, though I couldn't find any publication that included both.

Answer (score 2):

The only story I can think of that has an *author* go back in time using a *mirror* is L. Sprague de Camp's "[Balsamo's Mirror](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?50366)" (1976), where H.P. Lovecraft and a friend are sent back to the 18th century (which is close to what you remember) by a gypsy using a magic mirror.

They don't get trapped there, though; they come back when their 18th-century bodies are killed, and the mirror is broken.